# Is the name of a non-static-member dependent when used within a non-static member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, dependent-type

Both gcc 5.0 and clang 3.6 require the `typename` keyword in the following example:

```
template<int n>
struct I
{
    typedef int Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    int m;

    void f()
    {
        typedef typename I<sizeof m>::Type Type; // typename required
    }
};
```

This is covered by the following wording in the C++11 standard:

> [temp.dep.type]/8
>
> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a simple-template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template
>     arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent

So `I<sizeof m>` is dependent if `sizeof m` is value-dependent.

> [temp.dep.expr]/4
>
> Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent (because the type of the expression cannot be
>   dependent):
>
> ```
> sizeof unary-expression
> ```
>
> [temp.dep.constexpr]/2
>
> Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the unary-expression or expression is typedependent
>   or the type-id is dependent:
>
> ```
> sizeof unary-expression
> ```

So `sizeof m` is only dependent if `m` is dependent.

> [expr.prim.general]/8
>
> Within the
>   definition of a non-static member function, an identifier that names a non-static member is transformed to a
>   class member access expression

So `m` is the member in a class member access expression.

> [temp.dep.type]/4
>
> A name is a *member of the current instantiation* if it is
>
> - An id-expression denoting the member in a class member access expression (5.2.5) for which the type
>     of the object expression is the current instantiation, and the id-expression, when looked up (3.4.5),
>     refers to at least one member of the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof.

So it seems that `m` is a member of the current instantiation.

> [temp.dep.type]/5
>
> A name is a member of an unknown specialization if it is
>
> - An id-expression denoting the member in a class member access expression (5.2.5) in which either
>
>   - the type of the object expression is the current instantiation, the current instantiation has at least
>       one dependent base class, and name lookup of the id-expression does not find a member of the
>       current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof; or
>   - the type of the object expression is dependent and is not the current instantiation.

So `m` is NOT a member of an unknown specialization - it would be found by name lookup to be a member of the current instantiation.

> [temp.dep.expr]/3
>
> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains
>
> - an identifier associated by name lookup with one or more declarations declared with a dependent type,
> - a nested-name-specifier or a qualified-id that names a member of an unknown specialization

Since `m` is of type `int` and is not a member of an unknown specialization, neither of these bullets would make the id-expression `m` dependent.

> [temp.dep.expr]/5
>
> A class member access expression (5.2.5) is type-dependent if the expression refers to a member of the current
>   instantiation and the type of the referenced member is dependent, or the class member access expression
>   refers to a member of an unknown specialization.

When `m` is transformed to a class member access expression, it is still not dependent because it does not refer to a member of an unknown specialization.

Should `m` be treated as dependent? On a related note, should `this->m` be treated as dependent? What about `std::declval<A>().m` ?

**EDIT**

And finally, should `&A::m` be dependent?

Comment: How did I know this question would be from you? :) I thought it was clear from your previous questions that either the standard is improperly worded, or the compilers don't properly implement the standard. You will probably be able to find more examples where types or expressions that should be non-dependent according to the standard are treated as dependent by compilers.

Comment: Your question seems to be: "I have concluded that `sizeof m` is not dependent, but the compilers seem to think that is is dependent. Is there a flaw in my proof?" And the answer is: "No, I can't see any flaw." The same arguments should apply to `this->m` and `std::declval<A>().m`, since in any case the object expression refers to the current instantiation, and `m` has no dependent type.

Comment: I figure the answer to these questions may be useful to others in future - admittedly only to those that are implementing C++.

Comment: `this->m` is complicated by [temp.dep.expr]/2 "`this` is type-dependent if the class type of the enclosing member function is dependent"

Comment: Have you reported bugs in the two compilers? The response might be interesting.

Comment: `std::declval<A>().m` is complicated by the fact that the lefthand side of the class member access is type-dependent, making it impossible (?) to determine whether it refers to the current instantiation

Comment: Isn't the class member access expression that `m` is translated to just `this->m`? So if that is problematic, so is plain `m`.

Comment: @AlanStokes Good point, I missed [class.mfct.non-static]/3 "When an id-expression (5.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form
a pointer to member (5.3.1) is used in a member of class X in a context where this can be used (5.1.1),
if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class
C, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is
transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using (*this)"

Comment: [basic.def.odr]/2 "An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression
thereof." and [expr.sizeof]/1 "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is
either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized type-id"

Comment: It doesn't care that `this` in `this->m` is dependent, similarly for `declval<A>().m`. Both refer to the current instantiation, and `m` is a member of the current instantiation. It is possible to know prior to instantiation/specialization what `m` refers to, hence it's not dependent.

Comment: @dyp I think the type of `declval<A>()` cannot be determined until instantiation.

Comment: Oops, that might be right. I'll have to think about `declval` again.

Comment: @willj `A` is the injected-class-name that refers to the current instantiation ([temp.dep.type]/(1.1)). Is `declval<A>` really dependent then?

Comment: @Columbo Perhaps not, but it seems odd to perform overload resolution on `declval<A>()` when `A` is not yet instantiated.

Comment: @willj Hm. I think you're right. We can write `template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivial<T>::value>::type> T declval(); template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_trivial<T>::value>::type> T&& declval();` and hence make the return type dependent on properties of the template argument.

Comment: The quote in [expr.prim.general] I can neither find in N3337 nor N4140.

Comment: @Columbo In N3337, it's buried in a note in paragraph 8. The note is referring to [class.mfct.non-static]/3 which goes into more detail.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly stated by you, `sizeof m` is transformed into `sizeof (*this).m`.
`sizeof` is dependent only if the argument expression is type-dependent, which it isn't, according to [temp.dep.expr]/5:

> A class member access expression (5.2.5) is type-dependent if the
>   expression refers to a member of the current instantiation and the
>   type of the referenced member is dependent, or the class member access
>   expression refers to a member of an unknown specialization.

The type of `m` is not dependent, and the expression does not refer to a member of an unknown specialization either - [temp.dep.type]/6:

> A name is a member of an unknown specialization if it is
>
> - An *id-expression* denoting the member in a class member access expression (5.2.5) in which either
>
>   - the type of the object expression is the current instantiation, the current instantiation has at least one dependent base class, and
>       name lookup of the *id-expression* does not find a member of a class
>       that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class
>       thereof; or
>   - the type of the object expression is dependent and is not the current instantiation.

Even though the type of `(*this)` is dependent, it is the current instantiation. And name lookup should find `m` to be a member of the current instantiation.

So `*this` isn't type-dependent and thus `sizeof (*this).m` isn't dependent. (`sizeof m` is also not dependent outside any non-static data member initializer of function definition, which I accidentally covered in my second, deleted answer).

---

For `sizeof std::declval<A>().m` to be dependent, `std::declval<A>().m` must be type-dependent.
`std::declval<A>().m` *seems* to be type-dependent, but I'm not certain. As specified in [temp.dep.expr]/5 which I quoted above, the only possibility is that `m` in the expression is a member of an unknown specialization, which we have to show it is.

> A name is a member of an unknown specialization if it is
>
> - An *id-expression* denoting the member in a class member access expression (5.2.5) in which either
>
>   - the type of the object expression is the current instantiation, the current instantiation has at least one dependent base class, and
>       name lookup of the id-expression does not find a member of a class
>       that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class
>       thereof; or
>   - **the type of the object expression is dependent and is not the current instantiation.**

Here are the facts:

- The object expression `std::declval<A>()` is type-dependent.
- The lookup of `std::declval<A>` is only done in the definition context since it is a *qualified-id*, which are never *dependent names* ([temp.dep]/1).

There is exactly one `declval` function template found by qualified name lookup, but we cannot know if the return type of that candidate is the current instantiation at  definition time. Here in particular, `add_rvalue_reference` might have specializations not known at definition time (A scenario similar to [**this one**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e935cca8c4417ef/)). So because we do not know whether `std::declval<A>()` is the current instantiation, (we assume) it isn't, which makes the whole expression type-dependent.

---

`&A::m` is of the form `&`*qualified-id*, which is covered by [temp.dep.constexpr]/5:

> An expression of the form `&`*qualified-id* where the *qualified-id*
>   names a dependent member of the current instantiation is
>   value-dependent.

[temp.dep.type]/5:

> A name is a *dependent member of the current instantiation* if it is a
>   member of the current instantiation that, when looked up, refers to at
>   least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.

Clearly `A::m` is a member of the current instantiation, thus `&A::m` is value-dependent.
Also `&A::m` is type-dependent: The subexpression `A` is equivalent to `A<T>` according to [temp.local], which is a *simple-template-id* with dependent template arguments.

Comment: Might the downvoter explain the issue that lead him to his deed?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm an upvoter. It looks like [temp.dep.constexpr]/5 changed significantly since C++11.

Comment: Hmm.. by that logic, `A::m` should also be type-dependent. Clang disagrees: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wyfwluTHBOnCLZza

Comment: @willj I'm not entirely sure about my reasoning. Do you see any immediate flaws in it? (This might be a defect.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the linked example, I changed `m` to be static

Comment: @willj No, I overlooked it. :)

Comment: I can't see any obvious flaw in your reasoning. An id-expression qualified with `A` or `A<T>` would become type-dependent, which seems unnecessary and inconsistent. Consider that a type-name qualified with `A` or `A<T>` would not be dependent in the same context.

Comment: .. unless [temp.dep.expr]/5 somehow overrides [temp.dep.expr]/3. Even so, /5 wouldn't apply in the case of a static member.

Comment: @willj In particular, [temp.dep.expr]/(3.4) is the part that seems incorrect: `A<T>` is clearly a dependent type, but `A<T>::m` shouldn't be type-dependent if m is a member declared with a non-dependent type.

Comment: I wrote this problem up in my answer and posted a question on std-discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The answer hinges on whether `m` can be looked up to determine that it is a member of the current instantiation. The id-expression `m` is transformed to a class member access `(*this).m`, meaning that the rules for qualified name lookup within a class member access are applicable.

In general, the type of a type-dependent expression cannot be determined. It's not completely clear whether an exception should be made for `(*this).` and `this->`. An expression containing `this` is type-dependent, but both `(*this).` and `this->` unambiguously name the current instantiation.

### `m`

The expression `m` is indeed not type-dependent, because it refers to a member of the current instantiation.

In the context of a non-static member, `m` is transformed into the class member access expression `(*this).m`.

> [class.mfct.non-static]/3
>
> When an id-expression (5.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) is used in a member of class `X` in a context where this can be used (5.1.1), if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class `C`, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or `C` is `X` or a base class of `X`, the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using `(*this)`

The transformation occurs because `m` is a member of class `A` used within a non-static-member of class `A`.

> [expr.prim.general]/3
>
> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X, the expression`this`
>   is a prvalue of type “pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifer-seq and the end of the
>   function-definition, member-declarator, or declarator. It shall not appear before the optional cv-qualifier-seq
>   and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value
>   category are defined within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function).
>
> [expr.prim.general]/5
>
> The expression `this` shall not appear in any other context. [ Example:

```
class Outer {
    int a[sizeof(*this)]; // error: not inside a member function
    unsigned int sz = sizeof(*this); // OK: in brace-or-equal-initializer

    void f() {
        int b[sizeof(*this)]; // OK

        struct Inner {
            int c[sizeof(*this)]; // error: not inside a member function of Inner
        };
    }
};
```

> —end example ]

The above example explicitly permits use of `this` within a `sizeof` expression within a non-static member.

> [temp.dep.expr]/2
>
> `this` is type-dependent if the class type of the enclosing member function is dependent

Therefore `this` is type-dependent within the definition of a member function of a class template.

> [temp.dep.expr]/1
>
> Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.

However, the above is overruled by the exception in [temp.dep.expr]/5 quoted in the question.

### `this->m`

The expression `this->m` is also not type-dependent, because it is also a class member access expression which refers to a member of the current instantiation.

### `std::declval<A>().m`

The expression `std::declval<A>().m` has to be type-dependent, as the return type of `std::declval<A>()` could depend on the type of `A`.

> [temp.local]/1
>
> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injectedclass-
>   name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a template-argument-list,
>   as a template-argument for a template template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-typespecifier
>   of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent
>   to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in `<>`

Therefore `A` is transformed to `A<T>`.

> [temp.dep.type]/8
>
> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a template parameter,
> - a simple-template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template
>     arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent

This confirms that `A<T>` is a dependent type, meaning that `A` is also dependent.

> [temp.dep.expr]/3
>
> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains
>
> - a template-id that is dependent,

So `std::declval<A>` is a type-dependent expression. It follows that `std::declval<A>().m` is type-dependent because it contains the type-dependent subexpression `std::declval<A>`.

### `&A::m`

The expression `&A::m` logically has to be type-dependent because it has the type `int A<T>::*` which is a dependent type.

The expression `&A::m` is transformed to `&A<T>::m` because `A` is the injected class name - as shown above.

The id-expression `A<T>::m` is type-dependent according to [temp.dep.expr]/3 because it contains a template-id `A<T>` that is dependent. Therefore the expression `&A<T>::m` is type-dependent according to [temp.dep.expr]/1.

### `A::m`

The expression `A::m` is transformed to `A<T>::m` because `A` is the injected class name - as shown above. The expression `A<T>::m` is further transformed to `(*this).A<T>::m` because `A<T>::m` names a non-static member of `A`.

The id-expression `A<T>::m` is type-dependent according to [temp.dep.expr]/3 because it contains a template-id `A<T>` that is dependent. The class member access expression `(*this).A<T>::m` refers to a member of the current instantiation, so [temp.dep.expr]/5 applies but does not make the expression type-dependent - nor does it contradict [temp.dep.expr]/3.

### Defect?

Given the interpretation above, an id-expression naming a member of `A` qualified with `A` or `A<T>` would become type-dependent, which seems unnecessary and inconsistent. Consider that a type-name qualified with `A` or `A<T>` would not be dependent in the same context.

If the intention of [temp.dep.expr]/5 is that `(*this).m` is not type-dependent, then it follows that `(*this).A<T>::m` should also not be type-dependent. On the other hand, the intention could be that the name of a non-static member is always dependent. I've posted a question to std-discussion to clarify this point: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/gEvZ7mmXEC8

Comment: ... I somehow managed to miss the fact that the whole thing was inside a member function.

Comment: But the type dependence of class member access expressions is described in [temp.dep.expr]/5, which prevails over the general rule in [temp.dep.expr]/1.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, [temp.dep.expr]/1 says "Except as described below"